# What's the correct way to constrain a Date property?

Tags: validation, grails

The following constraint is unreliable because `new Date()` will only be [evaluated once](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/max.html), leaving you with a stale max date.

```
class Foo {
    Date date

    static constraints = {
        date max: new Date()
    }
}
```

So how do you reliably constrain a Date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the date cannot be greater than the current date of validation:

```
static constraints = {
    date(validator: { val, obj -> val <= new Date() })
}
```

Grails [validator](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html)

Comment: That's unfortunate if there's already another custom validator :(

Comment: If you have multiple validation rules in a custom validator, return different messages.properties keys instead of just returning true or false

Comment: If need to use complex custom validation see bond's reply on Dec 27, 2012; 10:30am
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/multiple-custom-validators-for-one-property-td4626746.html